# How to correctly manage state with normalized data

Tags: reactjs, redux

Suppose I'm normalizing the data for my app, and I end up with the state shape looking like this:

```
{ 
    entities: { profiles: { 1: {...}, ...}, roles: {...}, ... },
    profileList: [1, 2, 3],
    roleList: [1, 2, 3],
    profile: [2],
    ...
}
```

Now, suppose I have a profile list view, where all profiles are listed. If I add a new profile, I want the change to be reflected in the UI immediately, so I'd need to handle the `ADD_PROFILE` action in the `profileList` reducer, and in the correct part of `entities` in state.

What are the best practices of how to manage these changes?

On one hand, I can create fat actions and a simple entities reducer that simply merges the action response into entities. I like this because I could focus only on the non-entities reducers. I dislike this because then it seems like both my actions and my reducers depend on knowledge about how the state looks.

On the other hand, I could create separate reducers and combine them:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  entities: combineReducers({
    profiles,
    roles
  }),
  profileList,
  roleList,
  profile,
});
```

I like this because then I know only reducers know about how the shape of the state. I dislike it because it makes my life harder: 
- When adding a new profile I have to manage it in both the `profiles` reducer and the `profileList` reducer.
- It makes organizing code using this method harder.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your profiles and roles are for? Some context would help me understand what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Those entities are just examples. It could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

General suggested practice is to use "selector" functions to hide the state of your store shape in action creators and `mapState` functions.  As for the question of how to split logic, there is no single answer - do whichever works better for you.

The Redux FAQ covers this question: [Where should my "business logic" live?](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go)

Also, for working with normalized data I highly recommend the ([redux-orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm)) library, which puts a very nice Model-type facade on top of the normalized data in your Redux store, including managing relationships between entity types.